# react-native modal official example does not work with react-native-web, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-web

This is react-native official `<Modal />` documentation:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal.html

They have a live demo [here](https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-9nMRCakcg&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=razcrv10d5&supportedPlatforms=android,ios&name=Modal&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true)

[image]

The demo is for iOS and Android, I want to use `react-native-web` to target the web devices.

This is the same live demo used on the web: https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/excited-bagel

As you can see, the modal is not hidden, and animation does not trigger when clicking on hide/show

[image]

1. How can I fix the official modal so it can be used on the web?
2. Side and less important question, how can I add a clickable backdrop overlay to close it?